# Create data when the program is running assembly

Tags: assembly, tasm

Well, The question is simple: How can I allocate space for data in code.

I try to do the following:

```
ReadArrayLength PROC
pusha   
    messageArrayLength db "Enter the number of the bytes in array: $"
    mov dx, OFFSET messageArrayLength
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
popa
ret
ENDP
```

But when I'm debugging the program and call this procedure, my turbo assembler get stuck. Is there any way how can I create a new data field and manipulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution here seems to be jumping over the data:

```
ReadArrayLength PROC
  pusha   
  jmp @@1
  messageArrayLength db "Enter the number of the bytes in array: $"
@@1:
  mov dx, OFFSET messageArrayLength
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h
  popa
  ret
ENDP
```

Comment: Yeah, it's actually what I want, but how can I access this data, as far as I know, it allocates memory in code segment, that's why  `mov dx, OFFSET messageArrayLength` is the wrong command.

Comment: That may be true - like most people outside the educational system I haven't programmed for DOS in decades :) If that interrupt expects the data to be in the data segment you will need to declare it there instead. You are not showing your entire source file so I can't point to where that is (or if it is missing).

Comment: [`Int 21/AH=09h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) expects the address of the string in `DS:DX`. TASM calculates here the offset of `messageArrayLength` relative to the **code** segment. `DS:DX` points therefor to any address but not to the string.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of embedding data in the assembly code is:

```
some_proc proc near

  call @after_data  ; <-- store on the stack the return address

@return_address:    ; it will point exactly here

  db   'String',0   ; a string
  db   0FFh,0FEh    ; array of bytes
  dd   0ABBAh       ; DWORD

@after_data:

  pop  dx            ; pop the return address from the CALL
                     ; dx = offset @return_address
  ...    
some_proc endp
```

This creates offset independed code too.